# How can we use the SurveyMonkey API to programmatically decide what questions to ask?

Tags: surveymonkey

We love SurveyMonkey, and are researching how to connect it to our database using the API.  Seems straight-forward to pull data out of SurveyMonkey.

Once the data is in our database, we then want to use that data to programmatically decide what questions to ask in subsequent surveys.  It appears this *might* be possible in v3 of the API, but we're not sure how to do it in detail.

Here's the use case:

1. On Jan 1 we launch a survey to our members that asks 5 questions, including their gender.
2. Bob answers the survey, so we know he is male.  We store that in our database.
3. On Feb 1, we launch a different survey with 5 questions, one of which is gender.  Bob receives this survey, as do many others.  But because we already know that Bob is a male, we ideally don't want to ask Bob again.  So everyone else sees a 5-question survey, but Bob sees a 4-question survey.

In other words, for the Feb 1 survey we DESIGN and CREATE a 5-question survey, but when it is sent to Bob, we only sees 4 questions.

Would greatly appreciate any pointers on the best way to do this!

Comment: What have you tried? There a 1000s of ways to do this. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks tmthydvnprt.  We have not yet tried, for 2 reasons.  First, we contacted SurveyMonkey's support line and they said this was not possible but they couldn't explain why.  That seemed odd to us, since when we READ the API, it seems like it might be possible, but not obvious.  Instead of wasting hours trying to do something that the API doesn't support, we figured we would ask.  We know that SurveyMonkey monitors this channel.  Second, we have been told by Qualtrics (a SurveyMonkey competitor) that this isn't possible, and that we must switch to them.  That also seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple possible ways. One way is to use [Advanced Branching](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Advanced-Branching-Rules) (unfortunately can't be set by the API yet, you need to setup the survey through the application on the web).

You can create a custom variable (a url GET parameter), and then on your side programatically set that parameter before sending out the survey. The advanced branching rule can hide the question (or skip the page) based on the value of the parameter.

An alternative is to split out the gender question (or any other question you may already have) onto the first pages of the survey. Then [create a response](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses) in advance filling out the first page. You'll have the `edit_url` in the response body, you can send that link out and then the client would continue taking the survey from the incomplete pages forward.

Those are two ways I can think of right now that may work. There may be other creative ways to do what you'd like through the API.

Comment: Thanks!  Very helpful and detailed!!